# issue with Jfreechart to plot cluster index result

Tags: java, arrays

I have an issue with Jfreechart, In my cluster algorithm i have index which is has the format :

```
c[20][150] = min_idx;
```

The jfreechart method used has the argument bellow:

```
   public chartClass(String title,double[][] xs,double[][] ys,int[]k,double[][] cent) {
    super(title);
    JPanel chartPanel = createDemoPanel(xs, ys, k, cent);
    chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1000, 670));
    setContentPane(chartPanel);
}
```

for color mixture the code is :

```
for ( int j =0; j < c.length; j++){

  for (int i = 1; i < xs.length; i++) {

    plot.setDataset(i, new SampleXYDataset2(xs[i], ys[i]));
    XYDotRenderer renderer = new XYDotRenderer();
    renderer.setDotWidth(4);
    renderer.setDotHeight(4);
    plot.setRenderer(i, renderer);

    System.out.println("Part " + i + ", color " + c[j]);

    plot.getRendererForDataset(plot.getDataset(i)).setSeriesPaint(0,
            //Color.getHSBColor((float)i/ c[i] , 1.0F, 1.0F));  
            Color.getHSBColor((float) j/ (c[j]+1) , 1.0F, 1.0F));
   }   
}
```

the color is not changing according to cluster (cent) and does not separate the clusters according to index

Comment: What is your issue? Is any exception thrown?

Comment: Have you checked that the calculation of `j/ (c[j]+1)` does not return always the same value?

Comment: @kevin yes it returns  same value ??

Comment: What exactly is your datatype? because at the beginning you have a twodimensional array `c[20][150]` and then you have a singledimensional array `c[j]` ...

Comment: i convert 2D c to 1D  for passing it to the method:  the code is :             int[] c11 = new int[c.length * c[0].length];    
              
             for(int i = 0; i < c.length; i ++)
               {
                  for(int s = 0; s < c[i].length; s ++)
                      {
                      c11[(i * c.length) + s] = c[i][s];
                      }
                   }
              
              System.out.println(Arrays.toString(c11));

Answer (score 0):

Your method for transforming your array is wrong:

```
int[] c11 = new int[c.length * c[0].length];
for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
    for (int s = 0; s < c[i].length; s++) {
        c11[(i * c.length) + s] = c[i][s];
    }
}
```

Refactor to this:

```
int[] c11 = new int[c.length * c[0].length];
for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
    for (int s = 0; s < c[i].length; s++) {
        c11[(i * c[i].length) + s] = c[i][s];
    }
}
```

`c[i].length` is needed

Comment: I change it , still same

Comment: what are your values in the `c` field? only some of them e.g. 20 pieces

Comment: the values are index and  start in java from 0,1,2  in case k=2 index will be 0,1.

Comment: Have you tried it this way? 
Color.getHSBColor(1.0/(j + 0.0001) , 1.0F, 1.0F));

Comment: Color.getHSBColor(1.0/ (c[j]+1.0) , 1.0F, 1.0F));

Comment: Color.getHSBColor(1.0/(j + 0.0001) , 1.0F, 1.0F));  does not change the color at all , the second one is same as first time

Comment: Pls print the first 10 results of: `1.0/ (c[j]+1.0)`